# Подсчет количества ячеек в столбце

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста формулу или реализацию, нужно подсчитать количества ячеек в столбце данные которых больше числа в определенной ячейке, но не больше ее значения плюс определенное число.

Спасибо!

Проблемы добавляет то, что эти операции нужно делать со временем.

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так это надо сделать при помощи стандартных формул Excel или все-таки на VBA?

Comment: хоть как-то, главное реализовать

Comment: А ячейки, содержащие значения времени, отформатированы в формате "Время" или "Общий/Текстовый"?

Comment: В формате Общий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть возможность, то используйте значения времени отформатированные как время, так с ними можно делать любые вычисления, да и вид лучше:
[image: Пример работы в excel]

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как вычислять строчку от 30 минут до 1 часу, и я отмечу ваш ответ как правильный

Comment: `=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(B3:B6;">"&$B$2+"00:30:00";B3:B6;"<="&$B$2+"01:00:00")`